# Assign identifier values that include an original name in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame for which one of the attributes is the original object identifier number. I have split some of the records into two objects. Now, I would like to assign a new object identifier that includes the original name and a letter from a to z (fortunately my dataset has a maximum of 12 duplicates per original identifier). I found a method with a for loop but given that my dataset has over 750 000 records, it is very long. Is there something more straightforward than my solution? I have not yet mastered creating apply/dlyr type commands in R.

```
#create data.frame
sample = data.frame(ID_obj=c(1:6, 4, 2), x=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,4), y=c("a3", "4a", "5b", "8b"))

#reorder sample by ID_obj
sample<-sample[order(sample$ID_obj),]

#create empty vector
test<-numeric(0)
for (i in 1:6)
{
add<-letters[1:dt[i,"Freq"]]
test<-c(test, add)
}

sample$ID_obj_new<-paste(sample$ID_obj, test, sep="_")
#  ID_obj x  y ID_obj_new
#1      1 1 a3        1_a
#2      2 1 4a        2_a
#8      2 4 8b        2_b
#3      3 1 5b        3_a
#4      4 1 8b        4_a
#7      4 2 5b        4_b
#5      5 2 a3        5_a
#6      6 2 4a        6_a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution using the package `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(bindrcpp)

sample %>% 
    group_by(ID_obj) %>% 
    mutate(ID_obj_new = paste(ID_obj, letters[1:n()], sep="_")) %>% 
    ungroup()
```

Comment: System time from 30 minutes down to 1.2 minutes with this solution! Just added the libraries to add for the solution to work.

Comment: `bindrcpp` is unnecessary I think

Comment: It loaded automatically when I ran the command with a warning that it was built in the most recent version of R . So perhaps not necessary to load upfront but still necessary to run command...

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a concise solution which uses the `rowid()` function from the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sample)[, ID_obj_new := paste(ID_obj, letters[rowid(ID_obj)], sep = "_")][]
```

> ```
>    ID_obj x  y ID_obj_new
> 1:      1 1 a3        1_a
> 2:      2 1 4a        2_a
> 3:      2 4 8b        2_b
> 4:      3 1 5b        3_a
> 5:      4 1 8b        4_a
> 6:      4 2 5b        4_b
> 7:      5 2 a3        5_a
> 8:      6 2 4a        6_a
> ```

This will work even if `sample` is not ordered.